How can I convert a random forest model created in Python to a dat file?
I created a ramdom forest using Python and ran it using mlmodel on iOS.
I want to run it on Android, I'm trying dlib, but dlib requires a dat file as a model file. How can I generate it?
Dlib seems to have a cpp that reads dat files as model files:  http://dlib.net/dlib/test/random_forest.cpp.html
